# Storing words into Hashmap

Tags: java, servlets, hashmap

I am trying to parse a text file and store the first word as the key to a HashMap and store the remaining words as its value. What I'm attempting to do is to create a sort of translator where the user will enter a word in English (the key) and it would return the value (the Spanish translation, which may be more than one word). Here is a sample of the text file (note: I must also not store strings from lines that begin with the char '#'):

```
###########################################################################
#Copyright 1999 The Internet Dictionary Project/Tyler Chambers
###########################################################################
a   un, uno, una[Article]
aardvark    cerdo hormiguero
aardvark    oso hormiguero[Noun]
aardvarks   cerdos hormigueros
aardvarks   osos hormigueros 
ab  prefijo que indica separacio/n
aback   hacia atrás
```

UPDATED:I have updated the code to what I have so far. I am very close. One issue I'm having is dealing with (english)words that have multiple translations in spanish. The problem I'm having is dealing with these keys and values. What i would like to happen when a word has multiple translations is something like the following:
output: 
English: aardvark
Spanish: 1.cerdo hormiguero
         2.oso hormiguero[Noun]

Another issue I'm having is when the user enters a word that is not translated, showing a message saying that it cannot be translated. I used 
    if(request.getParameter("inputtext") != null)
to check but is not working. Any help would be appreciated!
    package lab1;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet("/Translate")
public class Translate extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static String realPath;
private BufferedReader reader;
public HashMap<String, String> lists = new HashMap<String, String>();

public Translate() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
    realPath = this.getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/Spanish.txt");
    File file = new File(realPath);
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "ISO8859-1"));
        String line = null;
        StringBuilder rslt = new StringBuilder();
        if(reader != null){
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if ((line.length()>0)&&(line.charAt(0) != '#')){
                    String [] tokens = line.split("\\s", 2);
                    if (lists.containsKey(tokens[0])) {
                        //handle the duplicates
                   } else {
                       lists.put(tokens[0].replaceAll("\\s",""), line.substring(tokens[0].length()).trim());
                   }
                }
            }
            Iterator iterator = lists.keySet().iterator();  
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {  
               String key = iterator.next().toString();  
               String value = lists.get(key).toString();  

               //System.out.println("KEY: " + key + " \nVALUE:" + value);  
            }
        }
            //System.out.println(rslt.toString());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Blah1");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head><title>English to Spanish Translator</title>");
    out.println("<style>h1,h2,form,p{text-align:center;color:white}body{background-color:black;}</style></head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<h1>Welcome to the Online Translator</h1>");
    out.println("<h2>Please Enter a Word in English:</h2>");
    out.println("<form method='post'><input id='inputtext' name='inputtext'></inputText><input type='submit' value='Translate' name='submit'></input></form>");
    out.println("</body></html>");
    out.close();
}
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String value = (String) lists.get(request.getParameter("inputtext"));
    if (request.getParameter("submit") != null) {
        if(request.getParameter("inputtext") != null){
                // word is found
                out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head><title>English to Spanish Translator</title>");
            out.println("<style>h1,h2,p{text-align:center;color:white}body{background-color:black;}</style></head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Here is your Translation of the word: " + request.getParameter("inputtext") + "</h1>");
            out.println("<h2>" + value + "</h2>");
            out.println("<p><a href='./Translate'>Translate Another Word</a></p>");
            out.println("</body></html>");
            out.close();
        } else if(request.getParameter("inputtext") == null){
            // word is not in translator
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head><title>English to Spanish Translator</title></head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>The Word " + request.getParameter("inputtext") + " is     not in the translation</h1>");
            out.println("<p><a href='./Translate'>Translate Another Word</a></p>");
            out.println("</body></html>");
            out.close();
        }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I suggest to use Properties instead of HashMap. English String as key and Spanish as value. Properties will take care of the comments for you.

Comment: You might want to consider writing this as a command line program rather than a servlet initially. It will be easier to see, deploy, and debug.  Once you get the data structures working, *then* make a servlet using them.

Comment: @Prem I will try doing it with Properties.

Comment: A couple more suggestions. You might want to process each line and store it into the HashMap directly instead of storing it into StringBuilder and iterate it again. Also, If you want to split each Spanish word and store it into the Map as values, the Data structure you use now may not be sufficient, either you use a Map<String,List<String>> or create your own data structure.

Comment: The problem with `#` is obviously a garden-variety bug, but note that with any sort of a "Map" you can only have one value for a given key.  Where more than one definition is attached (as with "aardvark") you can only have one of them, given your scheme.  You at a minimum need to attach a list of the terms (separated by comma or tab or maybe `|` or some such), or perhaps you should use a List in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you parse the line is wrong.
Try this (you can handle the space in a  better way, this is just a simple example):

```
    if(reader != null){
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if ((line.length()>0)&&(line.charAt(0) != '#')){
                String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+", 2);
                lists.put(tokens[0], tokens[1]);
            }
        }

        Iterator iterator = lists.keySet().iterator();  

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {  
           String key = iterator.next().toString();  
           String value = lists.get(key).toString();  

           System.out.println("KEY: " +key + " VALUE:" + value);  
        }
    }
```

The output is:

> KEY: aardvarks VALUE:osos hormigueros
>   KEY: a VALUE:un, uno, una[Article]
>   KEY: aback VALUE:hacia atrÃ¡s
>   KEY: ab VALUE:prefijo que indica separacio/n
>   KEY: aardvark VALUE:oso hormiguero[Noun]

However, the problem of the above solution is that it cannot handle duplicate KEY, new VALUE will replace the old VALUE if the KEY is same. If you want to fix this problem, call containsKey() method first before put the KEY-VALUE pair into the hash map:

```
  if ((line.length()>0)&&(line.charAt(0) != '#')){
      String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+", 2);
      if (lists.containsKey(tokens[0]) {
           //handle the duplicates
      } else {
          lists.put(tokens[0], tokens[1]);
      }
  }
```

Comment: I get an error on this line `code`lists.put(tokens[0],line.substring(tokens[0].length()+1)); unless I erase the +1 but then it doesn't give me the correct values.

Comment: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

Comment: Does the input text file has other special case than the example you give? You should handle those special case.

Comment: I'll check because I think you're right, there may be some special cases. How would I go handling theses special cases. Btw thanks!

Comment: You could ease this by using `String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+", 2);` then you will have an array with 2 elements as OP wish, no need to call `substring` then.

Comment: @user3162117 How about now? Thanks for Luiggi Mendoza's advice. It passes at my computer using the source you provided above.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, you're using `!=` to compare strings. That's a big no-no. Use `!string.equals(otherString)` instead.

`==` and `!=` compare the references of the strings rather than the values of the strings themselves, so  all your lines will be not equal.

You can probably get rid of the Strings completely over there by comparing the character to the # character: `line.charAt(0) != '#'`